# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...' is deniedの対処方法について

Tags: c#, unity3d

現在ゲーム上でキャプチャした画像を保存しようとしているのですが、記載のコードの最後の行にあるように、ファイルを書き込もうとすると以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...' is denied
```

アクセスが拒否された、ということで理由はいろいろありそうですが、自分で行ってみた方法ではどれも効果がありませんでした。

- 指定フォルダのプロパティから「読み取り専用」のチェックを外す。
- 管理者権限のアカウントでUnityも管理者として実行する。

これらを試してみましたが効果はありませんでした。
他にどのような対策があるか、どなたか知恵をお貸しください

```
 Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(CamTex.width, CamTex.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    RenderTexture.active = CamTex;
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, CamTex.width, CamTex.height), 0, 0);
    var TodayNow = System.DateTime.Now;
    fileName = eventName + "_" + TodayNow.Year.ToString() + "_" + TodayNow.Month + "_" + TodayNow.Day + "_" + TodayNow.ToLongTimeString() + "_" + takingPictures.Count + ".png";
    tex.name = fileName;
    tex.Apply();

    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    var path = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Pictures", fileName);
    Debug.Log(path);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

https://teratail.com/questions/288059
こちらでも質問しています。

Comment: 月並みですが`Pictures`フォルダがまだ無いとか？ [Android Unity c# : UnauthorizedAccessException writing save game data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46735735/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。一応再確認しましたがちゃんとありました。。

Comment: 該当パス名全てを`...`に省略するのは悪手では？ 個人名やアクセスキーなどの不味いところは同じ桁数の伏字にしてきちんと記述しておいた方が良いと思われます。状況把握のために推測が必要になり、ここやマルチポスト先のように確認コメントとかが増えるので。

Comment: 対象のフォルダが深い階層にある場合、保存先のアクセス権が適切であってもフォルダを辿る中間の階層でのアクセス権で弾かれている可能性もあります。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
階層に指定したPicturesフォルダを一度消してもう一度作成したところ、問題なく動作しました！
原因ははっきり言ってよくわかっていないのが気がかりですが、今回はとりあえず助かりました。
ご回答に協力していただいた方々もありがとうございます
[UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '...' is deniedの対処方法について](https://teratail.com/questions/288059?whotofollow=)